# Where to implement SimpleMembershipProvider in solution with MVC4 project and DAL project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

The structure of my solution is this:

[image: Solution tree]

I'm using `ÀSP.NET MVC 4` and the `DAL` project is using `Entity Framework 5` and `Code First` workflow. The `MVC` template has the `<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">` set and I need to implement `SingleMemebershipProvider` (not creating new template that is including it by default). I found several tutorials on this topic but for my scenario I wonder where is the place of the `SingleMemebrshipProvider`.

I want to use the existing database, and also I've read that it's just fine to map whichever table to be used by the `SingleMemebrshipProvider` (even though I plan on creating entity exactly for the purpose to deal with `SingleMemebrshipProvider`) but from this point of view it seems logically to include `SingleMemebrshipProvider` in my `DAL` project.

However it's services will be used from the `NVC` project and also I wonder if I won't break any conceptions if I try to set the `SingleMemebrshipProvider` in another project. The default template that provides `SingleMemebrshipProvider` has Controller - `AccountController`, Filter- `InitializeSingleMemebrshipProviderAttributes`, Models- `AccountModels` and maybe the `MVC` expects to find those classes.

However, I am not sure which approach to take. In a solution structured this way where is the place of the `SingleMemebrshipProvider`? (If possible explain why too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs to the ASP.NET MVC project if you ask me. I usually add a new folder to the web project called "Security". I put stuff, like the Membership and Role provider implementations inside this folder.

You should ask yourself if you are going to share the implementations along other web projects, if so then you could create a seperate project called NameOfProject.Web.Mvc and put all your mvc related stuff, like the Membership and Role provider, HtmlHelpers, Filters etc. here.

I use the same approach to seperate my REST services, based on Web API from the MVC project by moving them to a seperate project called NameOfProject.Web.Http.
This way it's very easy to build another client, like a console or winforms application that use the same service implementation as your other clients.

Here's an example of my project structure without a seperate project.

[image]

Example with a seperate project for MVC attributes

[image]

I hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: The idea of another project actually sounds very good to me. The thing that bothers me (because I have never used SimpleMembership or any other Membership provider) is won't that make too complicated using the features of the provider. The thing I can think of right now - if I create another project for the SimplerMP will only a reference from the MVC project to this one be enough to start using Attributes like AllowAnonymous, Authorize(Role.. etc, etc..?

Comment: Yes this will work like expected, because you register the provider inside the web.config under the section <membership> and <roleManager>. After registration through the web.config, you can use the mvc specific attributes like Authorize, AllowAnonymous etc. More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. I think this time I will stick to the original MVC project, as you initially suggested. Just to get used to the SingleMemebershipProvider. But I really like the idea for separation. +1 for that!

Comment: Glad to help out, yes it really depends on the situation. Go for the MVC project if you have just a couple of classes and seperate them to another project as they grow